# How to provide injected values while unit testing a component in angular5+

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular5

I am writing tests for a component that is initialized dynamically as a modal (entryComponent). Inputs for this component are retrieved via injector.
I need a way to provide these inputs in my component creation step in beforeEach.

```
this.modalService.create({
    component: sampleComponent, inputs: {
        test: 'testMsg'
    }
});
```

SampleComponent:

```
@Modal()
@Component({
    selector: 'sample-component',
    templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
    test: string;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.test= this.injector.get('test');
    }
}
```

Test for sampleComponent:

```
describe('sampleComponent', () => {
    let component: SampleComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SampleComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SampleComponent],
            imports: [
                ModalModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
            ],
            providers: [
                ModalService,
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
        })
    );
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SampleComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.ngOnInit();
    });
    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

test fails with:
 Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[test]:
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[test]:
        NullInjectorError: No provider for test!

How do provide value for 'test' in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In providers, provide values for the injected values that component is expecting:

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'test', useValue: 'valueOfTest' }
]
```